# jQuery prependTo not behaving as expected

Tags: jquery

```
$("#cont_div").css('display', 'none').html(data.html).clone().prependTo($("#newdiv")).slideDown(1000);
              $("#cont_div").empty();
```

This does not only copy the contents of #cont_div, but also #cont_div div itself. How could I make it only copy the contents of the element #cont_div (without the div tags)?

It's part of an ajax function.

Comment: .html() doesn't return object that's why chaining can't be done

Comment: Do you want `$("#cont_div").css('display', 'none').html(data.html()).clone().prependTo($("#newdiv")).slideDown(1000);
              $("#cont_div").empty();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about rewriting your code like this

```
$("#cont_div").css('display', 'none');

$(data.html).prependTo($("#newdiv")).slideDown(1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var content = $("#cont_div").html();
$("#newdiv").val("put new content here" + content);
```

This should take care of it.